# int function that returns an index from a vector of bools

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I have the following function:

```
int FamiliesController::returnFamilySelected(){

for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyCoosenController.size(); i++){

    if ( isFamilyChosenController[i] == true){

            return i;
        }   
    }
}
```

This function returns the index of a set of booleans, that when one of the is true it returns its index in the vector, very straight forward. The problem that I have now is that when all the booleans are false. The function returns a weird number -1029384. And the moment if I compare them like this:

```
int FamiliesController::returnFamilySelected(){

for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyChosenController.size(); i++){

    if ( isFamilyChosenController[i] == true){

            return i;
        }else if ( is FamilyIsChosenController[i] == false){
            return - 1;
     }   
    }
}
```

It will always return -1. Because it doesn't matter if only one element is true, once it passes that bool in the vector, it will return false right away, since the next one is false. I need to have the index of the one that has become true always be returned.

Is there anyway to tell it for example(pseudo code):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyChosenController.size(); i++){// we check in our vector of booleans

   if ( One boolean == true ){

       return the index of that boolean;

   }else if ( all the booleans == false ){

     return -1; // a number that is out of the container size but I can manipualte


}
```

Let's note here that I'm not using c++ 11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `return -1` after the loop. Either one of the values satisfies your condition and you return its index, otherwise the loop ends and you return -1.

That said, the idiomatic way to do this in C++ is using [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I should have seen that. But std::find only will tell me when a boolean has become true  or when all of them are false, since it uses iterators not indexes. How could I capture the index number of the boolean using std::find ?

Comment: Also, it's undefined behavior if your program reaches the end of a non-`void` function (which is why you got that weird number).

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: `std::find` returns an iterator to the item that matches. You can then `return std::distance(isFamily.begin(), return_value)` to translate that to an index. In this case, in practice the iterator will be a pointer and `std::distance` will do pointer subtraction but note that this is not guaranteed (and won't be true for all types of containers).

Answer (score 4):

your problem is that you dont return anything if you dont find a match

A good compiler will at least warn you about this

```
int FamiliesController::returnFamilySelected(){

for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyCoosenController.size(); i++){

    if ( isFamilyChosenController[i] == true){

            return i;
        }   
    }
}
// now what?????
```

You need to return a sentinel value to say 'not found'

```
int FamiliesController::returnFamilySelected(){

for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyCoosenController.size(); i++){

    if ( isFamilyChosenController[i] == true){

            return i;
        }   
    }
}
return -1; // not found
```

or you could throw

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code will only work as expected if the first element of the vector is true. Instead, you could try this:

```
int FamiliesController::returnFamilySelected(){

int index = -1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < isFamilyChosenController.size(); i++){

        if ( isFamilyChosenController[i] == true){

            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```